# Create xml file using shell script

Tags: shell

I'm trying to create a xml file using shell script with the below source code.

```
#!/bin/sh
header=`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<menu_details>`

fmt=`   <menu name="%menuName">
                <group name="%grpName" type="%M">
                        <page-details>
                                <page>
                                        <page-name>%pageName</page-name>
                                </page>
                        </page-details>
                </group>
        </menu>
`
footer=`</menu_details>`

{
printf "%s\n" "$header"
while read menuName grpName M pageName
do
        printf "$fmt" "$menuName" "$grpName" "$M" "$pageName"
done < "dd.lst"
printf "%s\n" "$footer"
} > dd.xml
```

Is it the proper way ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use single quotes for multi-line strings. Also the format specifiers you are using for printf are not correct:

```
#!/bin/sh
header='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<menu_details>'

fmt='   <menu name="%s">
                <group name="%s" type="%s">
                        <page-details>
                                <page>
                                        <page-name>%s</page-name>
                                </page>
                        </page-details>
                </group>
        </menu>
'
footer='</menu_details>'

{
printf "%s\n" "$header"
while read menuName grpName M pageName
do
        printf "$fmt" "$menuName" "$grpName" "$M" "$pageName"
done < "dd.lst"
printf "%s\n" "$footer"
}
```

Comment: This meet my requirements, thank you very much.